# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call in Passing custom array to procedure

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to call a procedure with custom type value but getting error

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call.

Not sure what is wrong?

ORACLE code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_cms_custodian_exigo_code
AS OBJECT
(
    fund_cust_exigocode_id           NUMBER,
    portfolio                        VARCHAR2(10),
    custodian_code                   VARCHAR2(15),
    security_exigo_code              VARCHAR2(30),
    cash_exigo_code                  VARCHAR2(30),



  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION obj_cms_custodian_exigo_code(
    fund_cust_exigocode_id           NUMBER,
    portfolio                        VARCHAR2,
    custodian_code                   VARCHAR2,
    security_exigo_code              VARCHAR2,
    cash_exigo_code                  VARCHAR2
  )
  RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
```

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ary_cms_custodian_exigo_code AS TABLE OF obj_cms_custodian_exigo_code

```
PROCEDURE save_cms_cv_cust_exigo_code
  (
      p_fund_cust_exigocode         IN OUT ary_cms_custodian_exigo_code,
      p_user_alias                  IN vew_user_alias.alias%TYPE
  )
  ...
```

Java Code :

```
Object[] array_of_records=new Object[1];
Object[] custodianExigoSaveKeyRecord=new Object[5];



STRUCT oracleRecord;

StructDescriptor custodianExigotype;  //for type
ArrayDescriptor custodianExigotypeTable;//for array



//create descripter for eatch oracle record

custodianExigotype = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("OBJ_CMS_CUSTODIAN_EXIGO_CODE", connNative);


//create a descripter for array of records
custodianExigotypeTable = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ARY_CMS_CUSTODIAN_EXIGO_CODE", connNative);


custodianExigoSaveKeyRecord[0]=Double.parseDouble("123");
custodianExigoSaveKeyRecord[1]="abc";
custodianExigoSaveKeyRecord[2]="abc";
custodianExigoSaveKeyRecord[3]="test";
custodianExigoSaveKeyRecord[4]="abc";
      System.out.println(" custodian Exigo save 22222222"+i);

  oracleRecord=new STRUCT(custodianExigotype,connNative,custodianExigoSaveKeyRecord);
   System.out.println(" custodian Exigo after creating STRUCT"+i);

   array_of_records[0]=oracleRecord;

  System.out.println(" custodian save 3333333333");

  ARRAY oracleArray=new ARRAY(custodianExigotypeTable,connNative,array_of_records);

  System.out.println("oracle array .."+oracleArray);

  System.out.println(oracleArray.getLength()+"  length of array .. "+oracleArray.getDescriptor());

  callstSave= conn.prepareCall("{call pkg_cms_custodian_exigo_code.save_cms_cv_cust_exigo_code(?,?)}");

  callstSave.setArray(1,oracleArray);
  callstSave.setString(2, "ABCUSER");//custodianExigoVo.getUserId()



  callstSave.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY);

  System.out.println("before calling proce dure ......");

  callstSave.execute();

  System.out.println("after calling procedure .........");

  Array outarray =callstSave.getArray(1);
```

Comment: I can see a possible issue, but I'm struggling to get the same error you are seeing. Which line in your code is that exception being thrown by; and which version of Oracle, Java and the JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Oracle:10,Java 8 ,JDBC14

Comment: If I comment callstSave.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY); able to call procedure but not getting out array ..

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly duplicate what you're seeing because I don't have an Oracle 10g DB available, but I can get slightly different errors with variations of your Java and JDBC version. (Why you're using JDBC14 is a separate question; 10g isn't supported of course, but see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03) and support doc ID 401934.1 for more on compatible versions).

Those errors can be resolved by including the type name in the `registerOutParameter()` call:

```
callstSave.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "ARY_CMS_CUSTODIAN_EXIGO_CODE");
```

---

Incidentally, your call to `oracleArray.getLength()` isn't going what you think and is probably always going to return zero; use `oracleArray.length()` instead to see the actual array size.